# How to override core catalog product option model file in magento2

Tags: product, custom-options, magento2.2

I want to get current custom  option's data while saving product and add it to my custom table.
I have tried it with two ways but similar error is thrown: **resource isn't set**

**First Way**:
In my di.xml :

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option" type="Namespace\modelname\Model\Product\Option" />
```

In namespace Namespace\modelname\Model\Product\Option.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Namespace\modelname\Model\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Option extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option 
{

     protected $optionsstock;
     protected $optionsstockcollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value $productOptionValue
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\Factory $optionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Validator\Pool $validatorPool
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
     * @param \Magedelight\CustomOptions\Model\OptionsStock $optionsstock,
     * @param \Magedelight\CustomOptions\Model\OptionResource\OptionsStock\CollectionFactory $optionsstockcollectionFactory,
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttributesFactory $extensionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeValueFactory $customAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Value $productOptionValue,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Type\Factory $optionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option\Validator\Pool $validatorPool,
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request,
        \Namespace\modelname\Model\OptionsStock $optionsstock,
        \Namespace\modelname\Model\OptionResource\OptionsStock\CollectionFactory $optionsstockcollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {      
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_optionsstockmodel = $optionsstock;
        $this->_optionsstockcollectionFactory = $optionsstockcollectionFactory;      
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $registry,
            $extensionFactory,
            $customAttributeFactory,
            $productOptionValue,
            $optionFactory,
            $string,
            $validatorPool,
            $resource,
            $resourceCollection,
            $data
        );

    }

     /**
     * Get resource instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
     * @deprecated 101.1.0 because resource models should be used directly
     */
    protected function _getResource()
    {
        return $this->_resource ?: parent::_getResource();
    }

      /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('\Magedelight\CustomOptions\Model\OptionResource\OptionsStock');
    }

   public function afterSave()
    {  
        parent::afterSave();
        /*$this->getValueInstance()->unsetValues();
        $values = $this->getValues() ?: $this->getData('values');
        if (is_array($values)) {
            foreach ($values as $value) {
                if ($value instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductCustomOptionValuesInterface) {
                    $data = $value->getData();
                } else {
                    $data = $value;
                }
                $this->getValueInstance()->addValue($data);
            }

            $this->getValueInstance()->setOption($this)->saveValues();
        } elseif ($this->getGroupByType($this->getType()) == self::OPTION_GROUP_SELECT) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('Select type options required values rows.'));
        }*/


        $productId = $this->_request->getParam('id');
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($this->getData());
        $optionsData = $this->getData();

        $this->SaveOptionsStock($optionsData, $productId);

        return $this;

    }

    public function SaveOptionsStock($param,$productId)
    {   
    try {

        $optionId = array();
        $ManageStock = array();

        if(isset($param['option_id']))
        {


            $optioncollection = $this->_optionsstockcollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$productId)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('option_id',$param['option_id'])
                        ->getFirstItem();


                $OptionsStockModel = $this->_optionsstockmodel;

                $optionId = $optioncollection->getMdId();

                if(!empty($optionId))
                {
                    $OptionsStockModel->load($optionId);
                }


                 $OptionsStockModel->setOptionId($optionsData['option_id']);                           
                 $OptionsStockModel->setManageStock($optionsData['md_option_stock']);
                 $OptionsStockModel->setProductId($optionsData['product_id']);
                $OptionsStockModel->save();                

        } 
         } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;

         }   



    }


}
```

**Second way is with plugin**:
In di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option">
    <plugin name="afterAfterSave" type="Namespace\modelname\Plugin\Product\OptionPlugin" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

In plugin file Namespace\modelname\Plugin\Product\OptionPlugin.php :

```
  <?php

namespace Namespace\modelname\Plugin\Product;

class OptionPlugin 
{  


    protected $optionManager;
    protected $optionsstock;
    /**
     * Http Request
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;

    protected $optionsstockcollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Namespace\modelname\Model\OptionResource\OptionsStock\CollectionFactory $optionsstockcollectionFactory,
        \Namespace\modelname\Model\OptionsStockFactory $optionsstock,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->_optionsstockcollectionFactory = $optionsstockcollectionFactory;
        $this->_optionsstockmodel = $optionsstock;
        $this->request = $request;
    }



    public function afterAfterSave(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $subject, $result)
    {     
          $productId = '2044';
        //echo "<pre>";print_r($this->getData());
        $optionsData = $subject->getData();

        try {

        $optionId = array();
        $ManageStock = array();

        if(isset($optionsData['option_id']))
        {


            $optioncollection = $this->_optionsstockcollectionFactory->create()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('product_id',$productId)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('option_id',$optionsData['option_id'])
                        ->getFirstItem();


                $OptionsStockModel = $this->_optionsstockmodel->create();

                $optionId = $optioncollection->getMdId();


                if(!empty($optionId))
                {
                    $OptionsStockModel->load($optionId);
                }


                 $OptionsStockModel->setOptionId($optionsData['option_id']);                           
                 $OptionsStockModel->setManageStock($optionsData['md_option_stock']);
                 $OptionsStockModel->setProductId($optionsData['product_id']);

                 $result =$OptionsStockModel->save();                

        } 
         } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            exit;

         }   

        return $result;
    } 


}
?>
```

I want it to work anyway and save data in my custom table but I am not getting what is missing here?
Can anyone please help me out for this!
Thanks

Comment: Have you get any solution. I have same issue.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293336/magento-2-override-for-product-custom-option-value-interface-and-model-file